# Is CiviCRM HIPPA compliant?

Tags: security

We are a non-profit mental health organization and require our records to be secure.

Comment: okay so there is confusion on Acronym, in forum it was also referred to as HIPPA (Health Information Privacy and Portability Act) but i also find http://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/index.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act so will vote to close on basis that the other one has correct acronym too

Answer (score 1):

There was quite a discussion about this [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=7788.0) which is worth your perusing. It suggests that the question won't be 'is civicrm HIPPA compliant' but 'is my configuration and usage of civicrm HIPPA compliant'.

Answer (score 1):

And in addition to what Pete wrote - you will want to ensure your server configuration/firewall/SSL etc is all set up securely too - and locked down such that only very few hands have access to your codebase.